# Login to two different pages according to roles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, authentication

My project has a Guest folder and an admin folder.

Guest has a guest1.aspx page and admin has admin1.aspx page.

Now I am trying to figure out a login control which will check the role of the user and send them to the respective pages accordingly.

The names are not in the database or the active directory...

These names are on the windows 2003 server...

So I need to check from the server if the user exists and what is its role in it..

what is the best way to achieve this... please any suggestions...

this is very important for me

any help is appreciated

thanks

@John_ Let me explain

Suppose there is company which has 10 employees and one administrator.. the company has a server and these employees are on the same domain. So the admin can add that machine to the server or delete it.. now every machine has its username password and domain.. i want my gui to use the same credentials to log into the gui and send them to the respective pages according to the role..

Comment: By "these names are on the Windows 2003 Server", do you mean that you're using Integrated Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 3):

In the [LoggedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) event check the roles of the user and use the [DestinationPageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl.aspx) property of the Login control to redirect to the proper page.

Comment: which login should i use windows or forms... and how to access the user roles... without they being in any database.. and i cant use active directory

Comment: If you don't have an ActiveDirectory it means you can't use Windows authentication. So use Forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples of checking the active directory group that the user is a member of here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#38